# How can I search for a string across all files of a project in Overleaf?

Tags: overleaf

I have a project in Overleaf containing several files (latex, bib, etc.).  How can I search for a string across all files of a project in Overleaf?

---

- I searched through the Overleaf documentation but couldn't find the answer.
- Example of project:  https://www.overleaf.com/project/new/template/16878?id=53614867&latexEngine=pdflatex&mainFile=ActaOuluExample.tex&templateName=Example+and+Guidelines+for+ACTA+OULU+LaTeX&texImage=texlive-full%3A2020.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Searching for a string across several files (latex, bib, etc.) in an a project in Overleaf is currently not possible. Source: https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf/issues/139

Answer (score 2):

The easiest workaround is to sync your project with Dropbox and search the synced files with a text editor like notepad++.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround:

1. Download all your projects to your local device (instructions here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Exporting_your_work_from_Overleaf ).
2. Unzip the downloaded file.
3. Search locally on your device for the string.